# Which games are two or more player in new NES Classic Edition?

Tags: nes-classic-mini

Nintendo is releasing the NES Classic Edition, a unit with 30 NES games on it.  I am wondering which of these 30 games will allow two or more players to play simultaneously.  I know Dr. Mario will allow this, will any of the 29 other games have two or more player functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the list of the games you can play as two or more (at the same time) on the NES Classic Edition :

- Balloon Fight
- Bubble Bobble
- Double Dragon II: The Revenge
- Dr. Mario
- Ice Climber
- Mario Bros.
- Super C
- Tecmo Bowl

So a total of 8 games on the 30. Of course, there is some more multiplayer games, but it's one player playing at the same time for those (such as the Super Mario Bros. games).